# How to extract $id from a Firebase array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/JjXOgKL

```
   var ref = firebase.database().ref();
     let list = $firebaseArray(ref);
    // I need help to extract $id from list
    console.log( list)
```

Hi, i need help to extract $id from list. Can anyone help? I have tried using list[0] but it gives undefined. Thank you. Would appreciate if you can show a codepen demo

Comment: can you explain the problem more briefly with sample data and the method/ways you have tried till now?

Comment: I used list[0]. Are you able to extract $id value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the `$id` by using `ref` on `value`. It has to be `promise` for you to be able to get `$id` and then with the you can loop through the `snapshot` to get the `key` which will be your `$id`

I highly rec-emend going through the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#node.js) here to `retrieve` data

[Working CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/alwayshelping/pen/yLOPmEX)

**Add this code:** (tested and works)

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
//var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    console.log('$id: ' + data.key); //$id
  });
}, function(errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Comment: Hi, do you know how to change the size of the picture when you click download. I want it to show in a smaller div or maybe a pop up box. Thank you.

Comment: @TestingSu Where is the question i can not see any question for that ?

Comment: Well, I posted it just know but removed by the community

Comment: @TestingSu Sorry i am not sure which question was it - i have no idea - You can post it again if you want too.

Comment: It is the same link https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/JjXOgKL

Comment: I have reached my question limit sorry

Comment: @TestingSu According to stackoverflow guidelines you have to post another question. I hope you are understand :) I wish i can help :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221034/discussion-between-testing-su-and-alwayshelping).